# What is the correct format for `child-resource-references` responses?

Tags: onem2m

TS-0004 Table 7.5.2-2 states that the `R/6` (retrieve child-resource-references) call (`?fu=1&rcn=6`) should return an `m2m:resourceRefList`. Is this correct? At least two open-source implementations i have seen return `m2m:URIList` for this query.

Is there anywhere listed examples that show a more complete list of responses for combinations of query parameters?

Comment: Do you mean ```?fu=1&rcn=6``` (rcn, not fcn)?

Comment: yes, sorry: `?fu=1&rcn=6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. fu=1 (discovery request) and rcn=6 should return a m2m:resourceRefList. Such as:

```
{
    "m2m:ch": [
        {
            "nm": "aResource",
            "typ": 99,
            "val": "cse-in/aResource"
        },
        {
            "nm": "anotherResource",
            "typ": 99,
            "val": "cse-in/anotherResource"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are a couple of examples in the developer guides: https://www.onem2m.org/developer-guides

Comment: what about `?fu=1&rcn=6` ? IMHO there are far too few examples. I'd like to see something like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_eQOpghaDnWzYZ672pvBS77yFupSVEuNORSO_qin2mY although some of those renderings are incorrect due to bugs in the implmentation i was using. i'd also like to see variants demonstrating how 'limit', 'offset' and 'level' affect the results because the language surrounding those is extremely vague.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I mean fu=1 (not 2). I updated my answer. And thank you for your input. You are completely right, there are way too few examples for a lot of aspect, not only for discovery. I am currently working on a couple of hands-on examples and discovery is definitely on the list.